# Windows Application Event Log and XFF

Tags: events, server, iis-8, error-logging

When IIS writes to the Windows Application Event log it adds the "User host address" (the users IP address), but this is not helpful when the XFF is being used (X-Forwarded-For). I have searched but could not find a way to include the XFF in the Application Event log when it includes the "User host address". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Add X-Forwarded-For column in IIS 8.5 and newer versions:

Custom logging became easier to configure with the IIS 8.5. Follow the steps below to add X-Forwarded-For column into IIS logs.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. On server, site or application level, double click "**Logging**"
3. Click "**Select Fields**"
4. In "**W3C Logging Fields**" window, click "**Add Field**"
5. In the "Add Custom Field" window, fill out the following fields

   **Field Name**: X-Forwarded-For, **Source type**: Request Header, **Source**: X-Forwarded-For
6. Click "**OK**" in both open windows
7. Click "**Apply**" in the actions pane

If your IIS version is before IIS 8.5, you can refer to the steps in this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/how-to-use-x-forwarded-for-header-to-log-actual-client-ip/ba-p/873115).

Comment: Not what I want. I know how to adjust the IIS logs. I want the Windows Application Event log when/where it adds the "User host address".